# How to update avatar/photoUrl on multiple locations in the Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, avatar

In Firestore I am trying to update avatar (photoUrl) on multiple locations when the user changes the avatar.

Data structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49V1I.png

Cloud function:

```
exports.updateAvatars = functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const userID = context.params.userID;
    const imageURL = change.after.data().avatar;

    console.log(userID);
    console.log(imageURL);
});
```

With this cloud function, I am watching on user update changes. When the user changes avatar I got userID and a photo URL. Now I want to update all "todos" where participant UID is equal to userID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `array_contains` operator for your query. This allows you to search for array values inside your documents.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

If you found your documents you have to update the URL on all documents and write the updated documents back to the database.

But this causes a lot of unnecessary writes especially if your `todos` collection gets bigger and you want to archive the `todos` data.

**Simpler solution:**

I suspect a to do list does not have more then 10 users if so this is a lot of trouble to save some document reads.

I would recommend you to just load all user documents you need to show the avatar on the to do list.